# Did the F-16 have an AoA limiter since the very first variant?

Tags: flight-controls, avionics, fighter, angle-of-attack, f-16

Did the F-16 have an AoA limiter since the very first variant or was it added later?

Answer (score 5):

The F16 was designed from the outset to be aerodynamically unstable with the computer keeping it within the constraints of the current flight envelope - including restricting the AoA to safe limits. In that sense, yes, it had an AoA limiter from the first production versions onwards.